# How to create local account on NIS clients?

Tags: nis

We have a NIS server with 4 NIS clients. I would to create local accounts on the NIS client in case the NIS server is offline. Our network is not stable and too many times the NIS server is offline.
Thank you for your help.

## /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:         compat

group:          compat

shadow:         compat

gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

networks:       files

protocols:      db files

services:       db files

ethers:         db files

rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Adding local users has nothing to do with NIS.

Comment: When the NIS server is down or offline users cannot login to the NIS clients (workstation). I would like to find a solution where although the NIS server is offline users can still login to the workstation. I thought by creating local accounts on the workstations it will help users to login.

Comment: Post your /etc/nsswitch.conf (add to the question details).

Comment: Sorry if the format is not exactly as in /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this should work for you (make a backup of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`). Change the passwd: and group: entries like this:

```
passwd: nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
group:  nis [NOTFOUND=return] files
```

Add a user that's in the NIS database, then shutdown the NIS client and test. This *should* force NIS to be the first lookup, then fallback to local  `/etc/passwd` if it's not found. Gotta admit, though - it's been decades since I've used NIS.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will give it a try. I have used NIS in the past and i never had a problem creating local accounts. This system was previously configured by another sys admin. Thank you again!